# Does an internal variable have more priority than a global variable?

Tags: python, variables, conflict, overwrite

I found a strange code regarding internal variables, which I don't understand the behavior:

```
artist = "ABBA"

def printer(artist):
    global internal_var 
    internal_var= "Queen"
    print(artist,"is an artist")

internal_var = "U2" # I added this line

printer(artist) 
printer(internal_var) # I thought this would be "U2" ...

print(internal_var) # I added this line; I thought this would be "U2" ...
```

The output is:

```
ABBA is an artist
Queen is an artist
Queen
```

I'm completely confused.
Firstly, why doesn't this lead to a conflict?
Secondly, why isn't `internal_var` overwritten?
Thirdly, how can I overwrite `internal_var`?

I think it's usable to a certain extent, but it will produce more bugs.

Please tell me if this question is a duplicate.
(I couldn't find any similar question.)
Thank you in advance.

Comment: I suggest you to put your code [python tutor](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit) and watch what happens step by step.

Comment: Why did you think that assigning `"Queen"` to `internal_var` would not assign `"Queen"` to `internal_var`?

Comment: Declaring a variable global makes it non-"internal" (with "internal" you probably mean "local").

Comment: @Asocia Thank you, very useful. I use the result to continue this discussion.

Comment: @MichaelButscher Could you elaborate on that? (By the way, the site introduced it as an `"internal variable"`.)

Comment: @Scott Hunter OK, I understand that the internal_var inside the printer() is "Queen". However, I still believe that the internal_var outside the printer() should be "U2".

Comment: What exactly do you think `global internal_var` means?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Firstly, why doesn't this lead to a conflict?
> Secondly, why isn't internal_var overwritten?
> Thirdly, how can I overwrite internal_var?

There is indeed a "conflict" in that the `internal_var` inside `def printer` has the same name as `internal_var` in the global scope.  Since you used the `global` keyword, the conflict is resolved by having both scopes reference the value that is defined in the global scope.  Normally, a local variable "shadows" any global-scoped variables with the same name (i.e. a distinct value is created for the local scope, and the global-scope variable becomes inaccessible).

If by "overwritten" you mean having its value reassigned -- it is.  That's why you see "Queen" in the list line of your output.

If you mean "overridden", as in "shadowed" with a different value as described above, it's because you used the `global` keyword and therefore explicitly prohibited the local variable from shadowing the global variable.

> I think it's usable to a certain extent, but it will produce more bugs.

**Yes.**  Using the `global` keyword is what I'd refer to as a "code smell" -- it's something you should (almost?) never do because it greatly increases the chances of mysterious bugs.  If you're just starting out, I would recommend avoiding it at all costs, and being suspicious of any tutorial you see that makes use of it unless it's in the context of a lesson that is just teaching you how it works (in case you have to debug someone else's code) before advising you to never actually use it.  :)

Comment: Thank you, now I understand. I have never used `global` before, so I got confused. I'd rather want to have an error message when they conflict. OK, I will never ever use `global`, even though it's good to know.

Answer (score 1):

Several comments are added into the code which make it clear how it works:

```
artist = "ABBA"

def printer(artist):
    global internal_var 
    internal_var= "Queen"
    print(artist,"is an artist")

internal_var = "U2" # I added this line; this line define global variable internal_var and set "U2"  
# note till this point we have two global variables as: (1) artist="ABBA" and  (2) internal_var= "U2"
print(internal_var) # display "U2" 

printer(artist) # internal_var is changed by printer to "Queen" because using global inside printer as "global internal_var" means you are referring to global variable internal_var.  
print(internal_var) # display "Queen"

printer(internal_var) # I thought this would be "U2" ... Note: you pass "Queen" not "U2", this prints "Queen" and change "Queen" to "Queen" again

print(internal_var) # I added this line; I thought this would be "U2" ... Note: internal_var is "Queen" not "U2"
```